# Create new pandas column with apply based on conditions of multiple other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `df` with time stamps in a basketball game (this is a sample. my actual df is much larger)

```
    year    period  p_sec_rem
0   2015    1   556
1   2013    1   455
2   2001    2   67
3   2008    3   177
4   2017    1   172
```

`period` is the period of the game and `p_sec_remaining` is the seconds remaining in the `period`. I would like to calculate how many seconds have elapsed since the beginning of the game (`time`) and have some logic that does this. It is a bit complicated, but explaining it is besides the point as I am sure it is correct:

```
df['time'] = None

def secondsPlayed(df):
  if df.year >= 2006:
    if df.period == 1:
      df['time'] = 600 - df.p_sec_rem
    elif df.period > 1 & df.period < 5:
      df['time'] = ((df.period * 10) * 60) - df.p_sec_rem
    elif df.period == 5:
      df['time'] = (((4 * 10) * 60) + 300) - df.p_sec_rem
    elif df.period == 6:
      df['time'] = (((4 * 10) * 60) + 600) - df.p_sec_rem
    elif df.period == 7:
      df['time'] = (((4 * 10) * 60) + 900) - df.p_sec_rem
  elif df.year <= 2005:
    if df.period == 1:
      df['time'] = 1200 - df.p_sec_rem
    elif df.period == 2:
      df['time'] = 2400 - df.p_sec_rem
    elif df.period == 3:
      df['time'] = (((2 * 20) * 60) + 300) - df.p_sec_rem
    elif df.period == 4:
      df['time'] = (((2 * 20) * 60) + 600) - df.p_sec_rem
    elif df.period == 5:
      df['time'] = (((2 * 20) * 60) + 900) - df.p_sec_rem
    elif df.period == 6:
      df['time'] = (((2 * 20) * 60) + 1200) - df.p_sec_rem
    elif df.period == 7:
      df['time'] = (((2 * 20) * 60) + 1500) - df.p_sec_rem
```

I would like to apply this logic to each row of my `df`, so I figured using `*.apply()` would do the trick, but alas:

```
df.apply(secondsPlayed,axis=1)

0    None
1    None
2    None
3    None
4    None
```

All `None` are returned, when my desired output is:

```
0    44
1    145
2    2333
3    1623
4    428
```

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46138428/pandas-dataframe-apply-returns-none-values#46138495) but I think it is slightly different from my example since I need to pass an entire df to the function as I utilize multiple different columns for the conditions that determine the output `df.time` value. I suspect I am close, but have been playing around with this for a while to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you could use vectorized operations instead of apply on `axis=1`. The idea is that before 2005, calculation of `time` depended on whether it's the first period or not. After 2006, it depended on whether it was before the 5th period or not:

```
import numpy as np
df['time'] = (np.where(df['year']<=2005, 
                      np.where(df['period']==1, 
                               1200, 1800 + 300*df['period']), 
                      np.where(df['period']<5, 
                               df['period']*600, 1200 + 300*df['period']))
              - df['p_sec_rem'])
```

Output:

```
   year  period  p_sec_rem  time
0  2015       1        556    44
1  2013       1        455   145
2  2001       2         67  2333
3  2008       3        177  1623
4  2017       1        172   428
```

Comment: this doesn't follow my logic or return the desired output

Comment: @bismo have you tried calculating Time for (2021 | 5 | 277) by hand? It's 2433, which is correctly calculated with my code, your code (and all the codes in the other answers here actually) are giving the wrong answer of 2723 because they all are missing a bracket in the if-else condition (because `&` has higher precedence than `>`), so for example, `df.period > 1 & df.period < 5` is equivalent to `df.period > (1 & df.period) < 5`, which is wrong. It should be `(df.period > 1) & (df.period < 5)`

Answer (score 1):

As you seem to want to use this function and `apply`, I'll answer this part.

Your function should take a row as input and **`return`** a value, which it doesn't at the moment:

```
def secondsPlayed(row):
  if row.year >= 2006:
    if row.period == 1:
      return 600 - row.p_sec_rem
    elif row.period > 1 & row.period < 5:
      return ((row.period * 10) * 60) - row.p_sec_rem
    elif row.period == 5:
      return (((4 * 10) * 60) + 300) - row.p_sec_rem
    elif row.period == 6:
      return (((4 * 10) * 60) + 600) - row.p_sec_rem
    elif row.period == 7:
      return (((4 * 10) * 60) + 900) - row.p_sec_rem
  elif row.year <= 2005:
    if row.period == 1:
      return 1200 - row.p_sec_rem
    elif row.period == 2:
      return 2400 - row.p_sec_rem
    elif row.period == 3:
      return (((2 * 20) * 60) + 300) - row.p_sec_rem
    elif row.period == 4:
      return (((2 * 20) * 60) + 600) - row.p_sec_rem
    elif row.period == 5:
      return (((2 * 20) * 60) + 900) - row.p_sec_rem
    elif row.period == 6:
      return (((2 * 20) * 60) + 1200) - row.p_sec_rem
    elif row.period == 7:
      return (((2 * 20) * 60) + 1500) - row.p_sec_rem
```

Then use:

```
df['time'] = df.apply(secondsPlayed, axis=1)
```

output:

```
   year  period  p_sec_rem  time
0  2015       1        556    44
1  2013       1        455   145
2  2001       2         67  2333
3  2008       3        177  1623
4  2017       1        172   428
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to return the `df` in your function:

```
def secondsPlayed(df):
    if df.year >= 2006:
        if df.period == 1:
            df['time'] = 600 - df.p_sec_rem
        elif df.period > 1 & df.period < 5:
            df['time'] = ((df.period * 10) * 60) - df.p_sec_rem
        elif df.period == 5:
            df['time'] = (((4 * 10) * 60) + 300) - df.p_sec_rem
        elif df.period == 6:
            df['time'] = (((4 * 10) * 60) + 600) - df.p_sec_rem
        elif df.period == 7:
            df['time'] = (((4 * 10) * 60) + 900) - df.p_sec_rem
    elif df.year <= 2005:
        if df.period == 1:
            df['time'] = 1200 - df.p_sec_rem
        elif df.period == 2:
            df['time'] = 2400 - df.p_sec_rem
        elif df.period == 3:
            df['time'] = (((2 * 20) * 60) + 300) - df.p_sec_rem
        elif df.period == 4:
            df['time'] = (((2 * 20) * 60) + 600) - df.p_sec_rem
        elif df.period == 5:
            df['time'] = (((2 * 20) * 60) + 900) - df.p_sec_rem
        elif df.period == 6:
            df['time'] = (((2 * 20) * 60) + 1200) - df.p_sec_rem
        elif df.period == 7:
            df['time'] = (((2 * 20) * 60) + 1500) - df.p_sec_rem
    return df
```

output:

```
    year    period  p_sec_rem   time
0   2015         1      556     44
1   2013         1      455     145
2   2001         2       67     2333
3   2008         3      177     1623
4   2017         1      172     428
```